# mtl file after exporting comes without texture map (map_kd ...)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, export, photogrammetry

I am quite new to blender. I have retopologized a high poly model with texture and then bake the texture  (all in cycles) to the new model in blender. When I export the obj file the mtl file comes without the map_kd texture reference. 
I exported with the following settings: Selection only, appply modifiers, Include edges, Write normals, Include UVs, Write materials and Objects as OBJ Objects (aso tried with "Material groups").

The texture is applyed with the following nodes: Image Texture - Diffusse BSDF - Material Output.

Any tip about what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the [.obj exporter requires a material setup using the *Principled Shader*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html) in order to write an .mtl with the `map_Kd` attribute. Unfortunately the documentation is still work in progress for Blender 2.8, that's [why this wasn't previously documented](https://developer.blender.org/T68704).

The fix for your problem is to replace the *Diffuse BSDF* nodes with the *Principled BSDF*. Then you can simply plug your texture into the base color socket of the *Principled BSDF*, set *Specular* to zero and it should export as expected.

Comment: In addition to this, please see [Duarte's elaborate answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/23985). It covers pretty much every export question regarding missing materials/textures.

Comment: In case you're writing add-ons, you want to replace creating `ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse` nodes with `ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled`.